# Postgres database deployed on fly.io connection string for EF Core

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, fly

> Fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004].
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'db' on server ' '.

The connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=dbname.internal;Port=5432;User Id=api;Password=password;Database=db"
```

I don't understand why it doesn't see the server

Comment: fly postgres connect -a db works

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true